# When binding, is it possible to specify the path on the source object?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

In a given binding, is it possible to specify the ***path*** on the ***source*** object?

It seems like this could avoid a lot of trivial converters.

Imagine the following example:

**C#:**

```
class foo
{
   bool A
   int B
}
```

**WPF:**

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="ListOfFoos" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding number, SourcePath=B}" />
```

Comment: Could you provide an example to make the question very clear.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the **SelectedValuePath** property is what you are looking for. It's inherited from Selector, so it will work for ComboBoxes, ListBoxes, etc.

Cheers, Alex

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

1. `DisplayMemberPath="B"` property of `ComboBox`
2. Custom template for each item

like this:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding B}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```